# How do you run programs forever in the background on Linux

Tags: node.js, server, linux-kernel, background-process

In a development environment to run a node.js script you type `node app.js`. However once you deploy your program on an actual Linux sever if you close the terminal it stops running your script. Is there a command that I can run that keeps that script running in the background even after closing the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely use **Forever** (https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) for this, however some newer linux distributions allow you to config services using **systemd** which is considered the better practice since it overlaps a bit with Forever in functionality.

You will easily find more information about it with a [quick google search](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=node%20js%20app%20as%20systemd%20service&oq=node%20js%20app%20as%20systemd%20service&aqs=chrome..69i57.7302j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 3):

A simple CLI tool for ensuring that a given script runs continuously , a one example is `forever`.

- first install forever globally

  npm install forever -g
- go to your project folder

  cd /path/to/your/project
- install `forever` monitor

  npm install forever-monitor
- now start your app using `forever`. lets say that your server is on
  app.js file-> to start just type

  forever start app.js
- now you can find the log file and the running `forever` instances
  by executing

  forever list
- to stop already running forever process just type

  forever stop 0 (0 is the process id )
- for more `forever`  commands

  forever --help

you can see installing guide and full documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

Answer (score 0):

A popular choice is PM2 (it daemonize application and run that app in the background).
Link: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/